# Is there an easy way to exit "meta"?

Tags: support, meta, stack-exchange

When you're on Arqade you can switch to Meta by clicking on a item in the Community Bulletin.

Is there a link to switch back to Arqade ? Other than editing the url (removing "meta.") or scroll to the bottom of the page and click "Arqade (gaming)".

Answer (score 8):

You can use the site switcher on the **top-right** of the page to switch between sites:

[image: site switcher]

Alternatively, the help button has a link as well:

[image: Help button link]